# Pixel 3 XL Android OS 10 Crash my app at start

Tags: android, android-10.0

My Application running fine till OS 9, but from OS 10, i tried in simulator as well in real device also getting below error, and i am total confused to get the root cause for this issue.

App start and crash,

Please check the crash log first

```
    --------- beginning of crash
A: FORTIFY: fclose: null FILE*
A: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 7718 (Thread-9), pid 7616 (com.mypackage)
W: type=1400 audit(0.0:46): avc: denied { read } for name="route" dev="proc" ino=4026532047 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_net:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.mypackage
I: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
I: received crash request for pid 7718
I: performing dump of process 7616 (target tid = 7718)
A: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
A: Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:10/QPP6.190730.005.B1/5775370:userdebug/dev-keys'
A: Revision: '0'
A: ABI: 'x86'
A: Timestamp: 2019-09-10 16:46:44+0530
A: pid: 7616, tid: 7718, name: Thread-9  >>> com.mypackage <<<
A: uid: 10132
A: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
A: Abort message: 'FORTIFY: fclose: null FILE*'
A:     eax 00000000  ebx 00001dc0  ecx 00001e26  edx 00000006
A:     edi eaac833e  esi c32df720
A:     ebp ef6dfad0  esp c32df6c8  eip ef6dfad9
D: getMobileDataEnabled()+ subId=1
D: getMobileDataEnabled()- subId=1 retVal=true
A: backtrace:
A:       #00 pc 00000ad9  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
A:       #01 pc 00092328  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (syscall+40) (BuildId: 76290498408016ad14f4b98c3ab6c65c)
A:       #02 pc 000ad651  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+193) (BuildId: 76290498408016ad14f4b98c3ab6c65c)
A:       #03 pc 00110db7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__fortify_fatal(char const*, ...)+55) (BuildId: 76290498408016ad14f4b98c3ab6c65c)
A:       #04 pc 00110dfd  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (fclose+61) (BuildId: 76290498408016ad14f4b98c3ab6c65c)
A:       #05 pc 00052a64  /data/app/com.mypackage-aCv7bNWbYro-EQG4TgLvAQ==/lib/x86/libgssc.so (GetDefaultGw(NIC_INFO_T*)+308) (BuildId: bddc468fe0bab0f449ceffa95424196fc7193cac)
A:       #06 pc 00041c78  /data/app/com.mypackage-aCv7bNWbYro-EQG4TgLvAQ==/lib/x86/libgssc.so (Java_com_starvedia_GSSc_NativeGSSc_entryPoint+616) (BuildId: bddc468fe0bab0f449ceffa95424196fc7193cac)
A:       #07 pc 00050cda  /data/app/com.mypackage-aCv7bNWbYro-EQG4TgLvAQ==/oat/x86/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline+138)
A:       #08 pc 0013e9a2  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #09 pc 00149a7a  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+298) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #10 pc 00332502  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+386) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #11 pc 0032c19c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+988) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #12 pc 00684d03  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+643) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #13 pc 001389a1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+33) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #14 pc 00336122  /data/app/com.mypackage-aCv7bNWbYro-EQG4TgLvAQ==/oat/x86/base.vdex (com.mypackage.a$a.run+26)
A:       #15 pc 002f8e0a  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.6689468213397061768+298) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #16 pc 002ffcc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+181) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #17 pc 0066fbd9  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1209) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #18 pc 0014503d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #19 pc 0013e7d2  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #20 pc 00149a69  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+281) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #21 pc 0055a513  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+99) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #22 pc 0055b91a  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+474) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #23 pc 005aaa51  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1585) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
A:       #24 pc 0011a8e5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53) (BuildId: 76290498408016ad14f4b98c3ab6c65c)
A:       #25 pc 000af6a7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71) (BuildId: 76290498408016ad14f4b98c3ab6c65c)
I: Application went to foreground
V: b: a() [52] - /system/xbin/su binary detected!
V: Using measurement service
V: Connecting to remote service
V: b: a() [52] - /system/xbin/su binary detected!
V: Activity resumed, time: 1721195
I: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
D: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=5867201387603550934}]
W: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
V: Using measurement service
V: Connection attempt already in progress
E: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
E: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
D: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D: eglCreateContext: 0xef27eec0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
D: eglMakeCurrent: 0xef27eec0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xef29ebc0)
E: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
E: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
D: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 16060416
E: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_10
W:   Force finishing activity com.mypackage/.activities.SplashActivity
I: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_10 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
I: add tag=SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
I: add tag=data_app_native_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
W: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
W: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
W: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
W: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
W: channel '2b8162c com.mypackage/com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
W: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 2232889 , only wrote 2226909
W: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 2226940 , only wrote 2226909
E: channel '2b8162c com.mypackage/com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
I: Process com.mypackage (pid 7616) has died: vis+99 TOP 
I: Process 7616 exited due to signal 6 (Aborted)
W: Device has associated, but no associated display id.
I: WIN DEATH: Window{2b8162c u0 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity}
W: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '2b8162c com.mypackage/com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity (server)'
W: setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 7616
W: Unable to start service Intent { act=android.service.appprediction.AppPredictionService cmp=com.google.android.as/com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.app.AiAiPredictionService } U=0: not found
W: could not bind to Intent { act=android.service.appprediction.AppPredictionService cmp=com.google.android.as/com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.app.AiAiPredictionService } using flags 67108865
I: #startMicroDetector [speakerMode: 0]
W: reportError [type: 211, code: 393244, bug: 0]: errorCode: 393244, engine: 0
I: Keeping mic open: false
I: #onError(false)
I: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10132 pid 7616 in 45ms
W: Activity top resumed state loss timeout for ActivityRecord{27c630b u0 com.mypackage/.activities.SplashActivity t-1 f}
W: Noting op not finished: uid 10097 pkg com.google.android.gms code 41 time=1568114204423 duration=-1568112450080
W: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 2404484 , only wrote 2316144
```

Manifest File Application tag

```
<application
        android:name=".activities.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="${appIcon}"
        android:label="@string/manifest_app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="${roundIcon}"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme,android:label,android:allowBackup">
```

Please let me know if you need any more information to debug it. i will share.. Not found any detail for this anywhere..

Help will be very much appreciable.

Please find stack trace

```
    --------- beginning of crash
FORTIFY: fclose: null FILE*
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 7597 (Thread-7), pid 7525 (com.mypackage)
Couldn't load memtrack module
failed to get memory consumption info: -1
Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;->mConstructorArgs:[Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-p, reflection, denied)
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.mypackage, PID: 7525
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage/com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.mypackage:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in com.mypackage:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.mypackage:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in com.mypackage:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.mypackage:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Field.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
     at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.ReflectionUtils.getValue(ReflectionUtils.java:29)
     at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:203)
     at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20)
     at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:239)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:659)
     at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:631)
     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.initWindowDecorActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:319)
     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:306)
     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:110)
     at com.mypackage.base.BaseAppCompatActivity.onCreate(BaseAppCompatActivity.java:112)
     at com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:86)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

In code we didn't have any layout file named "abc_screen_simple.xml" and when i search for it, i found its from

```
Gradle: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0@aar
```

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: Hey @MidasLefko updated the question with stack trace

Comment: seems like your issue is from this:

uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)